# How to connect to Elastic File System via SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, amazon-efs

I am trying to connect to my EFS mount folder via SFTP (FileZilla, WinSCP), is there any possibility to connect to an EFS mounted folder with SFTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have properly mounted your EFS file system in an instance where you have SSH access, you can directly access the files via SFTP without any special setup.

When mounted, the EFS file system functions transparently with the OS level file system. Make sure your permissions are appropriate for the login used to access the EFS files.

Comment: More tech details, please.

Comment: For example, use mount point on Linux file system called `/var/files` that mounts EFS FS at that path. Follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-getting-started.html. Then set your SFTP service default path to the EFS mount point above.